# How do you use components with data from Nuxt Content Module

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, nuxt.js

A component that has a hidden input field should have a the value of the current page title. In Nuxt you can accomplish it using **asyncData** for all pages except for pages using **Nuxt Content Module**. The Nuxt Content Module does not allow asyncData but **fetch** is allowed but. Example:

`components/Form.vue`

```
<template>
<div>
  <input
    id="page"
    type="hidden"
    :value="article.title"
    required
  />
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  async fetch() {
    this.article = await this.$content('articles', this.params).fetch()
  },
  data() {
    return { article: {} }
  },
}
</script>
```

`pages/articles/_slug.vue`

```
<template>
<div>
  <h1>{{ article.title }}</h1>
  <Form />
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  async asyncData({ $content, params }) {
    const article = await $content('articles', params.slug).fetch()
    return { article }
  },
}
</script>
```

This code gets no errors but the component never shows page title in the hidden input only in the h1 tag. (edit: fixed typo)

Comment: hello. did you get a solution for this?

Comment: Hi. Yes I figure it out, I will submit answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How I solved this was with props.

`components/Form.vue`

```
<template>
    <form>
        <label for="title"> Title </label>
        <input name="title" type="hidden" :value="title" required />
        <button type="submit">Send</button>
    </form>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
      default: ''
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

and then in the `pages/_slug.vue`

```
<template>
  <div>
    <nuxt-content :document="doc" />
    <Form :title="doc.title" />
  </div>
</template>
```

This should work for you.